# C# ActiveDirectory keeps returning false. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, active-directory, account-management

I know my Account Username and password. I am able to login to any PC on the domain.

```
Console.WriteLine("User Name: " + userName + " Password: " + tb.Text.ToString().Trim());
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext pc = new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAIN.TLD");                

// validate the credentials 
bool validatedOnDomain = pc.ValidateCredentials(userName, tb.Text.ToString().Trim());
return validatedOnDomain;
```

This method keeps returning false.

Am I doing something wrong here? I also know what my password is. Any assitance would be great!

tb -> TextBox where the password is being inputted. I remove all white spaces and trimmed it (in case a user screws up)

Comment: There are quite a few other questions on here (and elsewhere on the internet) that deal with `PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials` unexpectedly returning false. Have you looked at those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this :

```
bool validatedOnDomain = pc.ValidateCredentials(userName, tb.Text.ToString().Trim(), ContextOptions.Negotiate);
```

You just have to Specifie the options that are used for binding to the server.

Comment: I did that and still same issue.

Comment: Do you play with different context options ?

Comment: Yes but they all have similar results. For some reason, I tried the original code and it came as true. So the real problem is I am getting false when it should be true.